# can not find the error: Page not found (404)

Tags: django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Showing following error:

```
  Page not found (404)
  Request Method:   POST
  Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/toggle-attendance/%3E%3Cinput%20type=
  Using the URLconf defined in std.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
  ^events/ ^tonight/$ [name='ev_tonight']
  ^events/ ^create/$ [name='ev_create']
  ^events/ ^toggle-attendance/$ [name='ev_toggle_attendance']
  ^admin/
  The current URL, events/toggle-attendance/><input type=, didn't match any of these.
```

Template:

```
    <form method="POST" class="toggle_attendance_form" action="{% url ev_toggle_attendance %}>  
<input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="{{ event.id }}" />
        {% if attending %}
            <input class="attendance unattend" type="submit" value="Unattend" />
        {% else %}
            <input class="attendance attend" type="submit" value="Attend" />
        {% endif %}
    </form>
```

View:

def toggle_attendance(request):
    try:
        # going to assume values in the post parameter
        event_id = int(request.POST['event_id'])

```
# couple of possible errors: no event_id in POST parameter or value can not casted as int
except (KeyError, ValueError):
    # raising http404: means it couldnt be found
    raise Http404
# getting the event where id= event_id
event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
# 
attendance, created = Attendance.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user,
    event=event)
if created:
    pass
    # messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'You are now attending %s.' % event)
else:
    attendance.delete()
    # messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'You are no longer attending %s.' % event)

# Check to see whether the next variable in the POST parameters
next = request.POST.get('next', '')
if not next:
    next = reverse('ev_tonight')
return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
  toggle_attendance = login_required(toggle_attendance)
```

url:

urlpatterns = patterns('',

```
url(r'^tonight/$', views.tonight, name='ev_tonight'),
url(r'^create/$', views.create, name='ev_create'),
url(r'^toggle-attendance/$', views.toggle_attendance, name='ev_toggle_attendance'),
```

)

can you please help me finding the error?

Comment: Look at the servers error log - it will tell you what the request looked like. This should help you find the bug.

Comment: thanks and Its look like this.

[14/Jan/2013 22:21:27] "POST /events/toggle-attendance/%3E%3Cinput%20type= HTTP/
1.1" 404 2594

Comment: Maybe if you change the request to a "GET" just for debugging, you will see in the URL exactly how the request is formed

Comment: %3E%3C translates to `><` - any idea why they are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! You are missing a close quote at

```
<form method="POST" 
 class="toggle_attendance_form" action="{% url ev_toggle_attendance %}>
```

Which should be

```
<form method="POST" 
class="toggle_attendance_form" action="{% url ev_toggle_attendance %}">
```

Hope that solve it!